# Converting date formats

Tags: php

How can i convert a date of birth like 11/20/1978 to something like November 20, 1978 using PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like this:

```
echo date('F d, Y', strtotime($your_date));
```

### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/P0Eayuej)

Comment: Btw, where can i find a script to let me enter the dob in the 11/23/1999 format...